# Derivative of the composition of a function with a projection map

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, $q,q':\mathbb{R}^n\times \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ functions with $q'(x,y):=q(x,f(x))$ and $f,q$ continuously differentiable.

Let $i=1,...,n$. Calling $\phi:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n\times\mathbb{R}$, $\phi(x)=(x,f(x))$ and denoting by $D_i$ the $i-$th partial derivative:

> is it true that $D_i(q'\circ \phi)=(D_iq')\circ \phi$?

I have two ideas leading to different results... The first one is to compute $$D_i( q'\circ \phi) (z) = \lim_{h\rightarrow 0} \frac{q'(\phi(z+he_i))-q'(\phi(z))}{h}=\lim_{h\rightarrow 0} \frac{q(z+he_i,f(z))-q(z,f(z))}{h}=D_iq(z,f(z))=(D_iq)\circ \phi(z)$$

whereas the second one is to compute the product of the jacobian maps using the chain rule, which yields $D_i(q'\circ \phi)=((D_iq')\circ \phi)D_if=((D_iq)\circ \phi)D_if$.

I think the limit approach is wrong but I don't know where. Furthermore what is the correct result? Is it even true that $D_iq'=D_iq$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a mistake in the first computation: You write
$$
\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{q'(\phi(z+he_i))-q'(\phi(z))}{h} = \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{q'(z+he_i,f(z))-q'(z,f(z))}{h}.
$$
But note that
$$
\phi(z+he_i) = (z+he_i,f(z+he_i)),
$$
so the correct equality is
$$
\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{q'(\phi(z+he_i))-q'(\phi(z))}{h} = \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{q'(z+he_i,f(z+he_i))-q'(z,f(z))}{h}.
$$
Also, you are not aplying the chain rule correctly: You can write
$$
\phi(x) = (x_1,\dots,x_n,f(x)), \qquad x=(x_1,\dots,x_n),
$$
then, in classical notation,
$$
D_i(q'\circ \phi)(x) = \sum_{j=1}^{n}\frac{\partial q'}{\partial x_j}(x,f(x))\frac{\partial x_j}{\partial x_i} + \frac{\partial q'}{\partial y}(x,f(x))\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}(x).
$$
This implies that
$$
D_i(q'\circ \phi)(x) = D_i(q')\circ \phi (x) + \frac{\partial q'}{\partial y}(x,f(x))\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}(x)
$$
(Sorry for mixing notations). On the other hand, the equality $q'(x,y)=q(x,f(x))$ means that $q'$ does not depend on $y$ but only on $x$, because (sorry for my abuse of notation) $\partial_y (q'(x,y))  = \partial_y(q(x,f(x))) = 0$, thus
$$
D_i(q'\circ \phi) = D_i(q')\circ \phi.
$$

Now, note that by the chain rule,
$$
D_i q'(x,y) = \sum_{j=1}^{n} \frac{\partial q}{\partial x_j}(x,f(x)) \frac{\partial x_j}{\partial x_i} + \frac{\partial q}{\partial y}(x,f(x))\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}(x),
$$
so we have that
$$
D_i q'(x,y) = (D_iq)\circ \phi(x) + (D_{n+1}q)\circ \phi(x) D_if(x).
$$